# Embedding blow up to a Projectivization of vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$  be a smooth projective variety and $Z$  be smooth subvariety of codimension 2. If E is a vector bundle with surjection $E \to J_Z$, where $J_Z$ is the ideal sheaf of $Z$, then there is natural embedding $Bl_Z X \to \mathbb{P} _X (E^*)$. Are there other constructions to obtain embedding of blow up to the projectivization of some vector bundle?

Comment: Same works for arbitrary codimension. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find something else. Maybe codimension is important

Comment: These conditions are very close. For example, if you have a vector bundle mapping onto $J^n$ for some $n>0$, same thing works. In general, a reduction of the ideal or its powers and a vector bundle surjection to it is forced.

Comment: Mohan, thank. Do you claim, that it is all?